# MySQL error - incorrect DOUBLE value: 'chests'

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am trying to add a value to a specific user what is called `chests` when I execute this method:

```
public void addAmm(Player player, int amount, DataType type) {
    try {
        Statement sql = mySql.getConnection().createStatement();
        sql.executeUpdate("UPDATE `playerinfo` SET `chests`= '" + amount + "' + 'chests' WHERE Username='" + player.getName() + "';");
        sql.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It gives me this error:

> [12:26:14 WARN]: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated
>   incorrect DOUBLE value: 'chests'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume `amount` is `5` and `player.getName()` is `Paul`. What you get is:

```
"UPDATE `playerinfo` SET `chests`= '5' + 'chests' WHERE Username='Paul';"
```

So you assign `'5' + 'chests'` to `` `chests` ``. If this column is of type double, the assigned value has to be converted (truncated).

May be you wanted rather the following:

```
"UPDATE `playerinfo` SET `chests`= '5' + `chests` WHERE Username='Paul';"
```

i.e.

```
"UPDATE `playerinfo` SET `chests`= '" + amount 
                  + "' + `chests` WHERE Username='" + player.getName() + "';"
```

This adds `amount` to the value of column `` `chests` `` for player `Paul`.